# Angular6 ViewChildren host not changed when data binded updated

Tags: angular, angular6

I just noticed that ViewChildren hosts are not updated automatically.
Code like below:
In template:

```
    <div *ngFor="let compName of componentNames" item-wrapper>
                <ng-template demo-directive ></ng-template>
            </div>
@ViewChildren(DemoDirective) compHosts: DemoDirective[];
```

now if I change componentNames variable in the component, I found that compHosts are not changed still same quantity as of initialized.

I think this is because this variable was set then the parent component was first initialized, but when the binded variable got changed, this variable can not detect the change automatically.

I think there might be some method to refresh the compHosts here, but I can not find out the proper way to do that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Length of `ViewChildren` should have already be updated. But if you are displaying it in your template, you may need to run `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

Comment: Nice, it is just working. Thanks